# How to get Module params in component area in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

I want to get the module params in component area in joomla 2.5

Here my code :

> jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' ); 
>   $module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module'); 
>   $moduleParams = new JParameter($module->params); 
>   print_r( $moduleParams );

I try to print the `$moduleParams`...Its display nothing.
I got this code from the website http://www.themepartner.com/blog/25/retrieving-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/

Is there anyother way to get the params using the module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake

here the correct code

> jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' ); 
>   jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' ); 
>   $module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_randomads');  
>   $moduleParams = new JParameter($module->params);

Problem is `jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );` is missed

Comment: beat me to it :) glad you got it fixed

Answer (score 5):

for joomla 1.6 and higher

```
 jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' ); 
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_name');
    $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
    $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    $param = $moduleParams->get('paramName', 'defaultValue');
```

Hope this help cause jparameter is deprecated in j1.5 higher

You missed the actual link i think for 1.7 is http://www.themepartner.com/blog/56/get-joomla-17-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/

Comment: ThemePartner actually closed down their site, I've been looking for this page. Finally got an archive here: http://web.archive.org/web/20131001163031/http://www.themepartner.com/blog/56/get-joomla-17-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/

Answer (score 3):

For Joomla 3 you just need to do:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_name');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry($module->params);
$param = $moduleParams->get('param_name', 'default_value');
```